# media queries all use the same layout

Tags: css, media-queries

```
    /*media queries start here*/

    /*this is for modern laptops*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1336px) {

    .rectangle-box {
        position: relative !important; 
        width: 10% !important;
        height: 82% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        top: -10% !important;
    }

   #p-cactions {  
    top: 461px; 
    left: 410px; 
      }
        #button {
        display: none !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: -20% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 200 !important;
    } 

}
    /*this is for tablets*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {

       #border-search {
    position: absolute !important;   
    top: 80px !important; 
    left: 130px !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
      }
    #searchform {
        position: relative !important;
        left: -90% !important;
        top: 0% !important;
    }

    #p-cactions {   
    visibility: hidden;  
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 461px !important; 
    left: 30px !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
    }
    #mw-searchButton {
    position: relative !important;
    left: 210px !important;
    top: -460px !important;
      }
      #searchInput {
    position: relative !important;  
    top: -476px !important;
    left: -85px !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
      }
      li#n-mainpage-description {
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
    color: #FF7F27;
    top: 20px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 300;

    }

    li#n-recentchanges {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: 20px;
        left: -40px;
        z-index: 300;

    }

    li#n-randompage {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: -30px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }

    li#n-help {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: -65px !important;
        left: 120px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }

    li#n-add-pix {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: -85px !important;
        left: 220px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }
    /*media query edit links that appear only when logged in*/



    #ca-move {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 500px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-delete {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: -15px !important;
        left: 400px !important;
        text-indent:0;
        display:block;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-watch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        background: transparent;
        top: 35px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
        text-indent:0;
    }



    #ca-edit {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 15px !important;
        left: 510px !important;
    }



    #ca-protect {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 415px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #ca-unwatch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 570px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    /*media query edit links that appear when logged in and logged out*/

    #ca-history {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
    }

    #ca-talk {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 310px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-special {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-main {
        font-weight: bold;
        visibility: visible;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 700px !important;
    }

/*media query personal links*/

    li#pt-mycontris {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 140px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }

    li#pt-watchlist {
        visibility: visible;
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 380px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-preferences {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 220px !important;
        left: 390px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-mytalk {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 225px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }


    li#pt-logout {
    position: relative;
        top: 280px !important;
        left: 130px !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }

}

/*this is for portrait smartphone mode. don't use the !important tag. it stops it from working*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #border-search {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50% !important;
        left: 25% !important;
        display: none;
        }   
    #searchform {
        position: relative !important;
        left: -70% !important;
        top: 30% !important;
    }

    .rectangle-box {
        position: relative !important; 
        width: 80% !important;
        height: 12% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        top: -10% !important;
    }
    .rectangle-box2 {
        position: absolute !important; 
        width: 80% !important;
        height: 50% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        top: 12% !important;  

}
    #column-content {
        position: relative !important;
        display: block;
        width: 90% !important;
        margin: 1% !important;
        left: -4% !important;
        top: 30% !important;
    }

    #p-cactions {
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 410px;
        }   
    #button {
        display: block !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: -20% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 200 !important;
    } 

    #p-personal {
        display: none;
    position: relative;
        top: 280px;
        left: 130px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }

/*media query edit links that appear only when logged in*/



    #ca-move {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 500px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-delete {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: -15px !important;
        left: 400px !important;
        text-indent:0;
        display:block;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-watch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        background: transparent;
        top: 35px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
        text-indent:0;
    }



    #ca-edit {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 15px !important;
        left: 510px !important;
    }



    #ca-protect {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 415px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #ca-unwatch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 570px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    /*media query edit links that appear when logged in and logged out*/

    #ca-history {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
    }

    #ca-talk {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 310px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-special {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-main {
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative !important;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 100px;
    }

/*media query personal links*/

    li#pt-mycontris {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 140px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }

    li#pt-watchlist {
        visibility: visible;
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 380px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-preferences {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 220px !important;
        left: 390px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-mytalk {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 225px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }


    li#pt-logout {
    position: relative;
        top: 280px !important;
        left: 130px !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }
    /*navigation links*/
        #n-home {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 10% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }
        #n-sign-up {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 18% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }

}       
/*smartphone 4 to 4.5*/
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    #border-search {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50% !important;
        left: 25% !important;
        display: none;
        }   
    #searchform {
        position: relative !important;
        left: -70% !important;
        top: 30% !important;
    }

    .rectangle-box {
        position: relative !important; 
        width: 80% !important;
        height: 12% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        top: -10% !important;
    }
    .rectangle-box2 {
        position: absolute !important; 
        width: 80% !important;
        height: 50% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        top: 12% !important;  

}
    #column-content {
        position: relative !important;
        display: block;
        width: 90% !important;
        margin: 1% !important;
        left: -4% !important;
        top: 30% !important;
    }

    #p-cactions {
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 410px;
        }   
    #button {
        display: block !important;
        position: relative !important;
        top: -20% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 200 !important;
    } 

    #p-personal {
        display: none;
    position: relative;
        top: 280px;
        left: 130px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }

/*media query edit links that appear only when logged in*/



    #ca-move {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 500px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-delete {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        top: -15px !important;
        left: 400px !important;
        text-indent:0;
        display:block;
        background: transparent;
    }

    #ca-watch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: #FF7F27;
        background: transparent;
        top: 35px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
        text-indent:0;
    }



    #ca-edit {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 15px !important;
        left: 510px !important;
    }



    #ca-protect {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 415px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #ca-unwatch {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px !important;
        left: 570px !important;
        background: transparent;
    }

    /*media query edit links that appear when logged in and logged out*/

    #ca-history {
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 590px !important;
    }

    #ca-talk {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 310px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-special {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
    }

    #ca-nstab-main {
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        color: #FF7F27;
        position: relative !important;
        top: 20px !important;
        left: 100px;
    }

/*media query personal links*/

    li#pt-mycontris {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 140px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }

    li#pt-watchlist {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 250px !important;
        left: 380px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-preferences {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 220px !important;
        left: 390px !important;
        z-index: 300;
    }
    li#pt-mytalk {
        visibility: visible;
        position: relative;
        top: 225px !important;
        left: 600px !important;
        z-index: 300;

    }


    li#pt-logout {
    position: relative;
        top: 280px !important;
        left: 130px !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }
    /*navigation links*/
        #n-home {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 10% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }
        #n-sign-up {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 18% !important;
        left: 10% !important;
        z-index: 1;
        background: transparent;
    }

    /*smartphone landscape mode*/
}
/*media queries end here*/
```

my media queries show the same layout for every query. there supposed to change. I tested them before and they were working now they stopped working. Here is all the code for my media queries. I tested them on mobile, an my latop and the layout looked exactly the same. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you changed anything between them working and not working? Have you tested on multiple browsers, and cleared the browser cache/performed a hard refresh?

Comment: what's up with the !important everywhere? that's probably the problem

Comment: the important make the media query override default code. it doesnt work without it,